# If I block some people on Instagram would they be able to...?

Tags: instagram

1. See only my older posts or would they see none?
2. See only my older activity on the tab "following" on the app, or none?

By older posts and activity I mean those that I posted, liked, commented, etc. before I blocked them.

**Edit**:
In case that they were already following me before I blocked them, would they see that all of a sudden all my posts disappeared from my profile page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Instagram Help Page](https://help.instagram.com/447613741984126):

> When you block someone, that person can't view your photos/videos or search for your Instagram profile. People aren't notified when you block them.

But they can mention your username on Instagram, but this mention won't appear in your Activity. If you block someone and then change your username, they won't be able to mention you unless they know your new username.

After you block someone, their likes and comments are not removed from your photos and videos. You can delete their comments from your posts.

People that you block can still see your likes and comments on posts that were shared by public accounts or accounts they follow.

To know more about how blocking people works, see [Instagram Help Center](https://help.instagram.com/426700567389543/).

Comment: Thanks, edited my question to add some clarification regarding one particular case that is not on the help page.

Comment: For your edit, answer is the yellow highlighted one. They will not be able to see your photos and videos, so yes they will see that your post has disappeared from your profile.

Answer (score 1):

- 1) **None**
- 2) **None**

When you block someone, that person can't view your photos/videos or search for your Instagram profile. People aren't notified when you block them. However people that you block can still see your likes and comments on posts that were shared by public accounts or accounts they follow.

Comment: I see. Would that be true either if they were already flowing me before I blocked them? i.e. all of a sudden all my posts and activity would be hidden from them, even if they weren't before.